# How to update model without touching updated_at in ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have pretty simple code which changes only on column, like:

```
content = Content
  |> Repo.get(1)

content
|> Ecto.Changeset.change(%{ views_count: content.views_count + 1 })
|> Repo.update
```

I don't want this code to change its views count, but I don't want to touch `updated_at` field. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean you _want_ the code to change the view count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the question but this may work:

```
Content
|> where(id: 1)
|> Repo.update_all(inc: [views_count: 1])
```

Comment: This is nice and also fixes the race condition in OP's code.

Comment: Wonderful! btw, I haven't found any documentation about `inc` in ecto docs

Comment: @Dogbert can you elaborate on where the race condition is and how the provided solution solves it?

Comment: @AbM the original code fetches the `views_count` and then sets it to `views_count + 1` in 2 steps. If another piece of code modifies the row in between, the changes made by it will be lost. Using `inc` runs a single query making sure such a thing cannot happen (at least not due to this this query's fault).